# Keep only the last revision of content with multi-version module

Tags: 8

We are using Drupal 8 with the multi-version module version 1.0.0-alpha12.

As part of our dev/test workflow, we SQL dump the production database and move it into dev and test environments. Recently this process has been becoming increasingly slow and after some investigation into the composition of the database, I notice we have ~8G of data in the `node_revision__body` table.

I would therefore like to prune content in the database to keep only the most recent revision when we are working in our dev and test environments.

How can I achieve this with Drupal 8 and the multi-version module? I have come across the [Node Revision Delete module](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_delete), but that has a version for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, now (March 30 2018) it has a 8.x version. So this is your module:

[Node Revision Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_delete)

> The Node Revision Delete module lets you to track and prune old
>   revisions of content types.
>
> Features:
>
> - Define the max amount of revisions to keep per content type.
> - Run on Drush, cron run or on a different period (daily, weekly, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The node revision limit module if you happen to have multilingual sites.
The node revision delete do not work properly with Content Translation.

https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_limit